# Ansible-Playbook: ntpstat

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run this play book:

pi@rpi02:/etc/ansible/playbooks $ cat ntp.yml

```
---
- hosts: raspbian
  become: yes

  vars:
   ntp_server1: time.google.com

  tasks:
    - name: Ensure NTP (for time synclronization) is install
      apt: name=ntpdate state=latest update_cache=yes

    - name: Ensure ntpstat (to report the synchronisation state of the NTP daemon)
      apt: name=ntpstat state=latest update_cache=yes 

    - name: Start service ntpdate, if not started
      systemd: 
        name: ntp
        state: restarted
        enabled: yes

    - name: report the synchronisation state of the NTP daemon
      shell:
        name: ntpstat
# ...
```

Every things runs fine, except the last part.  I get this error:

> TASK [report the synchronisation state of the NTP daemon]
>   ******************************************************************************************************************************************************** fatal: [rpi02.daquezada.net]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
>   "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: name Supported
>   parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates,
>   executable, removes, stdin, warn"} fatal: [rpi04.daquezada.net]:
>   FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for
>   (command) module: name Supported parameters include: _raw_params,
>   _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, warn"} fatal: [rpi03.daquezada.net]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
>   "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: name Supported
>   parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates,
>   executable, removes, stdin, warn"} fatal: [rpi01.daquezada.net]:
>   FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for
>   (command) module: name Supported parameters include: _raw_params,
>   _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, warn"}  [WARNING]: Could not create retry file
>   '/etc/ansible/playbooks/ntp.retry'.         [Errno 13] Permission
>   denied: u'/etc/ansible/playbooks/ntp.retry'

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the very clearly stated error message? `Unsupported parameters for (command) module: name` means you cannot use `shell: name: ntpstat` like that, as the fine manual will tell you

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/shell_module.html) incorrectly as stated by the output:

> Unsupported parameters for (command) module: name Supported parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, warn

Your task looks like this:

```
   - name: report the synchronisation state of the NTP daemon
      shell:
        name: ntpstat
```

Should look like this:

```
   - name: report the synchronisation state of the NTP daemon
     shell: ntpstat
```

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested and now I am getting this:

Comment: fatal: [rpi02.daquezada.net]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ntpstat", "delta": "0:00:00.007701",
"end": "2018-11-11 19:04:04.371892", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1,
"start": "2018-11-11 19:04:04.364191", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [],
"stdout": "unsynchronised\n   polling server every 8 s",
"stdout_lines": ["unsynchronised", "   polling server every 8 s"]}

Comment: Surprisingly *ansible raspbian -b -m shell -a "ntpstat"* works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to send a slack notification when ntpq does not have any ntp server with a * next to it.  Not quite an answer but I got here trying to find a solutoin to this problem

```
- name: Check synced # noqa: no-changed-when
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: ntpq -p | grep '*' | wc -l
  register: p

- ansible.builtin.debug: # noqa: name
    msg: "ntpq output '{{ p.stdout }}'"

- name: Send notification message via Slack all options
  community.general.slack:
    token: "{{ SLACK_AUTH }}"
    msg: '{{ inventory_hostname }} ntp not synced'
    channel: '#sysadmin'
    username: 'Ansible on {{ inventory_hostname }}'
    color: danger
    parse: 'none'
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: p.stdout != '1'
```